# Javascript garbage collector on internally referenced object

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

I've been reading many SO questions about javascript garbage collection but this is just slightly confusing me. Take a look at my example

```
var valueObject= (function(){
    function valueObject(){
        this.Text = 'hello';
    }
    return valueObject;
})();

var referenceObject = (function(){
    function referenceObject (refObject){
        this.Reference = refObject;
    }
    return referenceObject ;
})();

var globalClass = (function(){
    function globalClass(){

    }
    globalClass.prototype.load() {
        this.A = new valueObject();
        this.B = new referenceObject(this.A);
    }
    globalClass.prototype.destroy() {
        this.A = null;
        this.B = null;
    }
    return globalClass;
})();

var Test = new globalClass();
Test.load();
Test.destroy();
```

Now once the Test object destroy has been called, will the valueObject and referenceObject be marked for collection?  Because `this.A = null` will remove the reference to the valueObject, but it still has a reference inside `this.B`. But if `this.B = null` is called, the reference to `this.B` is removed, but the `B` object will still be there with a reference to `A`?

Not sure if that makes any sense, it's a little confusing to me. Thanks.

Comment: Good garbage collectors can tell when the only references to an object are in garbage (or garbage-candidate) objects.

Comment: If you're going to drop the final reference to `Test` right after you call `.destroy()`, then I wouldn't bother with the `.destory()` at all, since the GC will take care of it.

Comment: 'The Joys of Static Memory Javascript' http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Op52liUjvSk

Comment: @Pointy so by good garbage collectors, would that refer to most browser GC's (IE8+)?

Comment: @cookiemonster The actual project is a lot bigger single page application with many more layers but it's rooted inside a single global object which will not be removed

Comment: @JamesHay strictly speaking it's not part of any specification. However, the nature of the language is such that a smart mark-and-sweep collector is probably the easiest thing to implement. Keeping track of things that the JavaScript runtime people are implementing is quite difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, it is convention to use names starting with a capital letter for constructors only, your code has that convention backward, mostly.

> Now once the Test object destroy has been called, will the valueObject and referenceObject be marked for collection?

Dunno about "marked", but available, yes.

> Because this.A = null will remove the reference to the valueObject

Yes

> but it still has a reference inside this.B

No, it doesn't.

Looking at the code (and fixing errors):

```
globalClass.prototype.load = function () {
    this.A = new valueObject();
    this.B = new referenceObject(this.A);
}
```

First, the *load* method adds an *A* property with a value that is returned by the call to  *valueObject*, which is just a plain object.

It then adds a *B* property that references another object with a *Reference* property that references the same object as *A*.

> But if this.B = null is called, the reference to this.B is removed, but the B object will still be there with a reference to A?

Yes, but since there are now no references to the object formerly referenced by *B*, and it's the only object that referenced the object formerly referenced by *A*, they are both available for garbage collection.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. So like Pointys comment on the OP, the GC can tell that the only references to the object are in places which are themselves, available for garbage collection. That makes sense.

Comment: Well, the GC ***should*** be able to do that. IE 6's famous memory leak was because it couldn't work that out—certain circular references were never garbage collected. ;-)